# Node in TikZ : change text alignment in one node ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I am working with tikz, and I am wondering if there is a simple way to have different text aligment in one node ?

For instance, in my MWE below, I would like to have *blabla1* centered, but *blabla2* and *blabla3* left aligned. For now I have tried to set left align by default, and to use \centering on *blabla1*; but it also centers *blabla2* (but not the third one...)

How to fix that and is there a better way ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,shapes}

\begin{document
\tikzstyle{block4} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=6cm, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
\centering
% Place nodes
\node [block4] (Foyer) 
                        {\centering{\emph{blabla1} }
                        \\ blabla2
                        \\ blabla3};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, use styles for nodes.

If you have a line with different alignment or different font size, end the line or the paragraph before the alignment or style is changed, i.e. `\\` should be inside, before the closing brace, here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto,
  block4/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=6cm,
                   rounded corners, minimum height=4em}]
  \node [block4] (Foyer) { {\centering \emph{line1} \\ }
                           line2 \\
                           line3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed it works, thanks. Can you explain a bit what you mean by in general, use styles for nodes.